# Display a web view aligned in the center

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a relative layout in which there is a textView and a WebView, I'd like to place both object in the middle of the screen (the WebView under the textView), here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:paddingTop="50dp">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/text1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/text2" />

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:id="@+id/text3"/>

</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/square2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/text6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

</LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linear"
    android:id="@+id/square2"
    android:src="@drawable/square"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/text5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/square2"
    android:text="Button" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

but it does not work because the webView is placed left while the textView is centered as it should (please see the image).
How can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

**Web View not aligned:**

[image: Web View not aligned]

Comment: Your XML was there for a minute you must have removed it. The webview had a top margin. There you go.

Comment: @SethCoast done

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman I have added the whole xml, I have tried to remove the top margin but it does not fix the problem

Comment: Hi there, the webpage/html you are rendering. Where is it coming from?

Comment: @FrancescoBordignon, I am trying to make sense of your xml. Can you provide a drawing of what you actually are planning to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the html you are planning to render isn't centred it wont matter how you position your WebView, also don't use wrap_content on the WebView use match_parent else you are compounding the problem.

The only way to centre html in your WebView would be

```
((WebView) findViewById(R.id.text6)).loadData("<body> <center> Hi </center> </body>", "text/html", "UTF-8");
```